# Shortcut to Connect to a Remote SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I was wondering if there's an easier way to connect to a remote ssh server. My school uses Zeus as our primary Linux login server.

I've been using Terminal and iTerm, but it's kinda slow to work there. I have to keep logging in and typing the password every time I want to open a new tab. And it doesn't even support the cursor.

Comment: What do you mean that it's slow? No matter the software, when you open a new instance/tab, it starts a new shell session where you are currently logged in. It's not going to start off connected to where you last connected via SSH. If it did, it wouldn't be any better because in the case where one wants to connect to multiple machines, it would be necessary to log out every time one opened a session.

Comment: Another thing that you can do, provided that you have the ability to install them, is to use `tmux` or `screen` which would allow you to open multiple sessions without having to log in each time but you would still need to do this each time you opened the application.

Answer (score 1):

First, to get better throughput, you might want to enable `Compression` in the config file.  Since generally most of what is being transmitted is text, a good amount of bandwidth can be compressed between the client and server.

Second, you might want to look into control sockets, which reuse the first connection being made to a system.  This will speed up the connections since only one is being torn down and set up.  Look for `ControlMaster`, `ControlPath` and `ControlPersist` in the `ssh_master(5)` manpage.

Third, you may want to look into running `screen(1)` or `tmux(1)` on the remote system which will allow you to create virtual tabs there and be able to switch between them without opening new ssh connections.

Lastly, look to create SSH private/public keys (c.f. `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-agent`), so you are not using passwords to log in.  These are more secure and will be used to encrypt the data between the two machines (which you would also want).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best option, but if you want to skip learning how to handle terminal multiplexers like `tmux` or `screen`, you could try running an X-window terminal emulator with multi-tab support via `ssh`.

Note that X applications via `ssh` are possibly slow (maybe not for the low load of a terminal emulator) and running them via `ssh` might be forbidden from the server side altogether.

Nevertheless:

**Search for possible emulators on the server**

Assuming `bash`-shell

```
ssh user@server 'echo $PATH | tr : \\n | while read line ; do find $line | grep -i term ; done'
```

**Running the emulator remotely**

If the list returns e.g. `gnome-terminal`, run:

```
ssh -X user@server 'gnome-terminal'
```

Again, possibly slow, possibly not enabled, possibly the server has no fitting emulator, and some emulators even have names without 'term' in them.